# Build a Maven project via Jenkins CI with external jar, not integrated in pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, jar, continuous-integration

I got a legacy project from bitbucket hooked up with Jenkins on a Docker container. The build fails, because an external jar is only available through a link.

I tried to download the jar via curl in the Jenkins file and created an own my-jar-pom.xml for it:

```
pipeline {

    agent {docker {image: 'maven: 3.6.3'} }

    tools {
        jdk "jdk-1.8"
    }

    stages {
        stage('myStage') {
            steps {
                step('Get Library') {
                    >&2 echo 'Get Library'
                    sh 'curl -O link-to-my-jar.jar'
                }
                step('Create POM') {
                    sh 'echo "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd\">\n
                                 <groupId>my-group-id</groupId>\n
                                 <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>\n
                                 <version>1.0</version>\n
                             </project>" > my-jar.pom'
                    >&2 echo 'create POM'
                }
                step('Install POM') {
                    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my-jar.jar -DpomFile=my-jar.pom
                    >&2 echo 'install POM'
                }
                step('Install') {
                    sh 'mvn -B clean install'
                    >&2 echo 'install mvn'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all that happens in the Jenkins file. Now the build still fails and I can't even read the echos I put between the commands in the console.
What is the solution to this? Download the file manually and put it somehow on the jenkins_home volume itself? I would prefer to solve this issue in the Jenkins file.

Edit: There error from the Jenkins console:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not
resolve dependencies for project my-project:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find my
jar in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty
releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
reattempted until the update interval of thirdparty-releases has elapsed
or updates are forced
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following things where missing: 
1) Installing JDK in the tools section of my Jenkins
2) Installing Maven in the tools section

then I changed the agent to `agent any` and added maven to the tools:

```
agent any

tools {
    jdk "JDK-8"
    maven "Maven-3.6.3"
}
```

-DgeneratePom=true didn't really work out, probably my fault, but I found experimented and found this as a working solution:

```
stages {
    stage('AXSUTILS') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Get Library'
                sh 'curl -O http://link.to.my.jar/my-jar/1.0/my-jar.jar'

                echo 'create POM'
                sh 'echo "<project xmlns=\\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\\" xmlns:xsi=\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\" xsi:schemaLocation=\\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xs\\"> <groupId>com.xx.xml</groupId> <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId> <version>1.0</version> </project>" > my-jar.pom'

                echo 'install POM'
                sh 'mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my-jar.jar -DpomFile=my-jar.pom'

                echo 'install mvn'
                sh 'mvn -B -U -X clean install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also watch out for missing quotes, I spent a good amount of time realizing Jenkins deletes \" so you need \" to have the " left.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. It should work.

But you need not create the POM yourself. You can let `install:install-file` create it. Just add `-DgeneratePom=true`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately it still doesn't work. I took a look at the console output from the Jenkins build, but there isn't even a hint. Any idea?

Comment: The output says that Jenkins was not able to download the jar. This can have several reasons: Firstly, it might be a cache problem: Try to build with `-U`. Secondly, you may have the wrong repository address or the artifact is not in that repository. Thirdly, you may have a network/proxy/firewall issue here (very often the case).

Comment: I discovered that I configured my job as a Maven project which seems to ignore the jenkinsfile. After creating a second Job as a Multibranch Pipeline, the console outputs ((install - file) - DgeneratePom) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at install-file -DgeneratePom=true The Download should work, as I tried it in my console.